# UIAppearance - Right place to put

Tags: ios, uiappearance

I'm trying to change the navigation bar of my app but I can't figure out where exactly to put this code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar.png"]]];
```

I have already tryed on de AppDelegate and on viewDidLoad of the first view, but it still doesn't work.
Is this code wrong? Where can I put it?

Regards!

**EDIT**

When I put this code on the delegate it works fine on iOS 6, but still not working on iOS 5.0 and 5.1!

Answer (score 2):

This should work in your AppDelegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

If it does not work, it is probably because of something else.
Are you sure that `[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar.png"]` does not return `nil` for example (if you removed the `navigationBar.png` from the "Copy Bundle Resources" build files of your target by mistake, for example, or if you have some typo in your file's name)…

Comment: This is actually wierd because when I put this code on the delegate it's not working for iOS 5.0 and 5.1, it works just fine on iOS 6. I'm edeting the question right now

Comment: Oh. Still, did you check the that the `imageNamed` does not return `nil`? (Maybe something changed here in iOS6 to make it laxist and find the image or sthg… I don't believe it but it's worth checking)